# How to change the multidimensional array to a nested array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I convert the following array: (Assume I don't know how many depth of the array and key names)

```
$array = array(     
'ycol'=>array('1'=>array( 'name1'=>array('data1',array('a','1'),'data3')),  
'2'=>array('name2'=>array('data1',array('b','2'),'data3')),           
'3'=>array('name3'=>array('data1',array('c','3'),'data3')),           
'4'=>array('name4'=>array('data1',array('d','4'),'data3')),           
'5'=>array('name5'=>array('data1',array('e','5'),'data3'))
);
```

into the following format: (Please show me how to use the recursive)

```
$array = array(
array('head'=>'name1','head1'=>'data1','o1'=>'a','o2'=>'1','head2'=>'data3'),
array('head'=>'name2','head1'=>'data1','o1'=>'b','o2'=>'2','head2'=>'data3'),
array('head'=>'name3','head1'=>'data1','o1'=>'c','o2'=>'3','head2'=>'data3'),
array('head'=>'name4','head1'=>'data1','o1'=>'d','o2'=>'4','head2'=>'data3'),
array('head'=>'name5','head1'=>'data1','o1'=>'e','o2'=>'5','head2'=>'data3')
);
```

I am new to PHP and need the help!

Thank you!

Comment: Where is `'head'` in the multidimensional array?

Comment: 'head' is the key need to add for 'name1'. same as th rest.

Comment: If you don't know the depth of the arrays or their key names, how would you know what goes where in the resulting array? What should be assigned to the `head` key? what should be assigned to `o1`? -- Also: where does this data come from? perhaps it's easier to look for a solution to your problem there

Comment: $array = array('xcol'=>array('head','head1','o1','o2','head2')); Another array needs to be matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your syntax and depth is always the same, the above can be done messily as below.

There are cleaner ways to do it, but you have not provided anything you have tried to handle the recursion.

```
$output = array();
foreach($array['ycol'] as $iteration){
    $head = array_keys($iteration);
    $sub = $head[0];
    $output[] = array(
        'head' => $sub, 
        'head1' => $iteration[$sub][0], 
        'o1' => $iteration[$sub][1][0],
        'o2' => $iteration[$sub][1][1], 
        'head2' => $iteration[$sub][2]
    );
}

$array = $output;

print_r($output);
```